# How to use inline entity form field in custom form?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have a site with Drupal 8 and Commerce 2. Now trying to build a custom "Create new order" -form for admin. Created a custom module and form with buildForm() function.
Managed to add selection for store and user (as entity reference fields) but I got stuck when trying to add products for order. I had an idea to use inline entity form for this, but I can't figure out how to do that.

In *buildForm*() function I have

```
 $form['products']['ief'] = [
    '#type' => 'inline_entity_form',
    '#entity_type' => 'commerce_order_item',
    '#bundle' => 'default',
    '#form_mode' => 'default',
    '#op' => 'add'
  ]
```

This shows 3 fields (Product variation auto complete field, quantity and unit price) but it does not show "*Create new order item*"-button.
Should this work out-of-box and is there something wrong with field settings...?

Or do I need to add submit button and some ajax callback myself to generate new fieldset?

Any help is appreciated :)